# Elements of composite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $K\subseteq F,L \subseteq \Omega$ be fields such that $F/K$ and $L/K$ are finite extensions (don't know if this is necessary). Prove that
> $$\alpha \in LF \Longrightarrow \alpha = \sum _{i=1}^nf_il_i \qquad f_i \in F,\ l_i \in L$$

I don't understand why this is true (and also don't know if the finite extensions requirement is necessary). My attempt was to observe that $LF=L(F)$ by definition, and so $\alpha \in LF=L(F) \Longrightarrow \alpha \in L(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ for some $f_1,\dots,f_n \in F$, and this implies that $$\alpha=\frac{p(f_1,\dots,f_n)}{q(f_1,\dots,f_n)} \qquad \text{for some }p,q \in L[x_1,\dots,x_n],\ q \neq 0$$
But I don't know how to arrive at the linear combination from this rational function. Is it the right way? How can I finish it?

Comment: Hint: Consider simple extensions first.

Comment: It depends on how you have defined the composite field. If you have defined it as the intersection of all fields in $\Omega$ containing both $F$ and $L$, then you could prove that the set of all such linear combinations constitute a field, and that this field contains both $F$ and $L$, thus contains the composite. Then you would be done.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim thank you very much, this answers my question. Does the converse holds (the composite contains all this linear combinations)?

Comment: @LuigiTraino That's a good question, but I think you know the answer if you spend a moment thinking about it.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim to be honest, I can't even prove that the set of such linear combinations is a field. It's definitely a ring, but I tried to search the inverse element of a generic combination $\sum\limits _{i=1}^n f_il_i$, and it doesn't seem to go anywhere

Comment: Maybe proving that the linear combinations constitute a field is actually more difficult than proving your result in another way. You original method might be wiser; all you need to check is that elements in $L(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ in fact have the form $\alpha = p(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ for some polynomial over $L$, you don't need to consider fractions of polynomials. This follows directly from the construction of field extensions.